# Finding the largest value

Tags: excel

I have a worksheet which lists all the sales opportunities for our business.  Each opportunity has the name of the group within the business, as well as the value, date, etc.  I can use the LARGE function to find, for example, the three largest values in the worksheet, but how would I find the three largest values for each individual group?  Would I need to set up a pivot table for each group and do it that way?  Btw, I don't have access to VBA so rely must on Excel's standard functions.

Thank you for any help you can provide.

Answer (score 1):

Let your group names be in column `A` and values in column `B`, then you can use this array formula

```
=LARGE(IF(A:A="GROUP_NAME",B:B),1)
```

note that you should press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>ENTER</kbd> to evaluate it.

If you need second or third laargest value, than change `1` to `2` or `3`. If you want to sum all this values, see @pnuts formula in comments below..

Comment: Bah, beat me to it. Nice answer though.

Comment: This is good stuff.  I've adapted the answers to fit the worksheet I have, but the result is showing as 0.  When I click the function button (fx) to see the various argumants it gives the correct value as the formula result, but this is not showing in the cell.  Any ideas?

Comment: have you pressed CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER to evaluate formula or just enter??